# python Django returing <WSGIRequest: GET'> instead of data

Tags: python, django

I some have trouble representing API data to my templates.

Some info:
The API data is send to context_processors.py in my app dir.

```
from ttn.context_processors import my_function

while True:
    my_function(SomeClass().return_data())
    time.sleep(5)
```

and here is my context_processors funtion:

```
def my_function(complex_data):
    all_data = complex_data
    return {'data': all_data}
```

complex_data looks like:

```
{0:{}, 1{}} etc..
```

Here is where I want to represent the data in my `base.html`:

```
<div class="div-side">
     {% if data %}
         <p>{{data}}</p> # this one return wsgirequest: get /myapp/
      <ul>
          {% for dicts in data %}
              <li>dicts</li> # just for test
                  {% for d in dicts %}
                     <li>{{ d.name }}
                      <span>{{d.someDigit|floatformat:'2'}}</span>
                      <span>{{d.somePercent|floatformat:'2' }} %</span>
                      </li>
                        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
           {% endfor %}
      {%else%}
          <p>no info</p>
           {%endif%}
</div>
```

My views which render to `base.html`:

```
def home_page(request):
    a = len(get_news_objects())
    return render(request, 'base.html',
                  {'a': a}
                  )
```

Basically I'm not able to represent my data at my `.html` page because `context_processors.py`, returns this "wsgirequest: get /myapp/".
What am I missing? How can I send the data instead of `wsgirequest: get /myapp/` ?

From my `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'project.context_processors.my_function', #
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: What is that infinite loop with a `time.sleep(5)` supposed to do??

Comment: Makes a request to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, what a silly mistake by me.

It turned out that I have overwritten the `request` name as first parameter at `context_processors.py`'s funtion, and I was trying to get information from `django.http.request`, instead of my data from my function.

Currently my code looks like this:
`context_processors.py`. Missreading the documentation...

```
def my_function(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = data_from_while_true_loop.
        return {'data': data}
```

It's working fine for now!